# Oracle trigger call procedure which starts a workflow

Tags: plsql, triggers, oracle11g, workflow, procedure

I have the following issue:
I created a trigger which is activated when a row is inserted into the table.
The trigger then starts a procedure. 
The procedure then starts a workflow.

When I start the procedure it works fine. But when I start the trigger by entering a new row I got the following error:

```
Zeile 12: ORA-20001: Task not found - Please check the Task Type, Name and Location are correct.
ORA-06512: in "OWBSYS.WB_RT_API_EXEC", Zeile 759
ORA-06512: in "OWB***.EXECUTE_WF_ABC", Zeile 10
ORA-06512: in "OWB***.START_EXECUTE_WF_ABC", Zeile 7
ORA-06512: in "OWB***.ABC_WORKFLOW", Zeile 2
```

This is my trigger:

```
create or replace
TRIGGER  ABC_WORKFLOW
BEFORE INSERT  
ON OWB***.STG_ABC  
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN  
OWB***.EXECUTE_WF_ABC;   
END ;
```

This is my procedure:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE        EXECUTE_WF_ABC

AS
  status   NUMBER;
  -- paramlist VARCHAR2(30000 CHAR);
BEGIN

   owbsys.wb_rt_script_util.set_workspace ('OWBREPOWN.OWB***');
   status :=
      owbsys.wb_rt_api_exec.run_task (
       p_location_name => 'OWF_LOCATION',
       p_task_type => 'PROCESS',
       p_task_name => 'WF_ABC',
  --     p_custom_params => paramlist ,
       p_system_params => '', 
       p_oem_friendly => 0 ,
       p_background => 1); -- execute in background

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (status);
   COMMIT;
---   EXCEPTION
---   when others then
---   message;
---      null;

END;
```

Did I miss something here?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your table is the TASK table, then your trigger is firing BEFORE the row exists, so if that workflow is checking for data in the row you're inserting then there is no wonder it's failing.

also `COMMIT;` in a trigger is really bad (and would fail if you inserted more than 1 row).

Comment: hi,the workflow is not checking for data in the table. the problem is that can not get the workflow running. it causes the error which I have listed in my question. somehow the trigger can not find the procedure. as I understand it. But thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @Ibo the trigger is finding the procedure just fine. you can see that in the error message. the failing code is "OWBSYS.WB_RT_API_EXEC" your code is throwing a user defined exception: ORA-20001: Task not found - Please check the Task Type, Name and Location are correct.

Comment: @ibo so the question is, what in the code causes it to throw that error. as its a user defined expection, only you can tell us that.

Comment: hi, if I only knew whats causing the error. The thing is - when I just start the procedure it works fine. Do I have to put the Task Type and so on as a parameter into the procedure in the trigger ?